# What causes the perception of time

Tags: brain, perception

I've recently watched veritasium video about time perception. And what i got out of that is that the more are brain is being used up the slower time goes and the less we use the faster it goes. Is this the right way to think of the way we perceive time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the mechanism behind time perception?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/what-is-the-mechanism-behind-time-perception)

Comment: Also related: [Perception of time as a function of age](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/129/7604) plus [How does body temperature affect perception of time?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1734/7604) and [How does our brain sense the passage of time?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24536/7604)

Comment: well it was moved from one site to this one so I of course have no power over it. And secondly i think that my question is unique enough to contend with does related questions

Comment: If you can't tell us why the other questions do not answer your question, your question will be closed as a duplicate. This is just standard procedure to prevent bloat.

Comment: Because my question excludes other things like circadian rhythm as an explanation its more of a is this right then what is the answer to the question